# Create map key value from array of JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array which looks like this -

```
[
 {name: 'Alex', date: '05/17/2023 10:32 PM', id: '00153168', priority: '3-Medium'},
 {name: 'Peter', date: '05/17/2023 11:32 PM', id: '00153169', priority: '3-Medium'}
]
```

Expected :

```
{
name : ['Alex','Peter'],
date : ['05/17/2023 10:32 PM','05/17/2023 11:32 PM'],
id: ['00153168','00153169'],
priority: ['3-Medium', '3-Medium']
}
```

Here is the attempt I made -

```
let arr = [];
data.forEach((number, index, array) => {
let keys = Object.keys(array[index]);
    for(i in keys){
        let a = data.map(item => item[keys[i]]);
        let b = keys[i];
        arr.push({b:a});
        
    }
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Any help should be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First, JSON is a string. You have an array of objects. 
Next, when you push your object `arr.push({b:a});`, it's setting the object key to the string "b". You'll want to create a temporary object and use bracket notation to set the key dynamically. `temp = {};
        temp[b] = a;
        arr.push(temp);`

Comment: @mykaf I am getting duplicate items in the return array with above changes. Can you please help?

Comment: You're iterating over `data` twice: `data.forEach(...)` and `data.map(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1kBlm)

```
/** converts list of objects into object of lists
  * keeps missing values in arrays, so objects don't have to be uniform
  * as simple as possible, does not use reducers and reconstructing
  */
function transpose(list) {
    const result = {};
    for (const i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(list[i])) {
            (result[k] ??= [])[i] = v;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that the shape of all of the objects in your array are uniform, you can first get the keys of your final data with the first element in your array.

Then just loop over your keys. Grabbing all of the values for each of those keys on every iteration. You can use map to access nested elements even in a complex object. Once you have the values, you can add them to a new object.

When you iterated over all your keys, you should have the data in the shape you need.

```js
const data = [
 {name: 'Alex', date: '05/17/2023 10:32 PM', id: '00153168', priority: '3-Medium'},
 {name: 'Peter', date: '05/17/2023 11:32 PM', id: '00153169', priority: '3-Medium'}
]


const keys = Object.keys(data.at(0));
let consolidatedObject = {};

for (const key of keys){
  const keyData = data.map(x => x?.[key])
  consolidatedObject = {
    ...consolidatedObject,
    [key]: keyData
  }
}

console.log(consolidatedObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [
 {name: 'Alex', date: '05/17/2023 10:32 PM', id: '00153168', priority: '3-Medium'},
 {name: 'Peter', date: '05/17/2023 11:32 PM', id: '00153169', priority: '3-Medium'}
];

const o = arr.reduce((a, e) => {
  for (let k in e) {
    a[k] = a[k] || [];
    a[k].push(e[k]);
  }
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(o)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
 {name: 'Alex', date: '05/17/2023 10:32 PM', id: '00153168', priority: '3-Medium'},
 {name: 'Peter', date: '05/17/2023 11:32 PM', id: '00153169', priority: '3-Medium'}
]

const result = data.reduce((a,c) => 
  (Object.entries(c).forEach(([k,v]) => (a[k]??=[]).push(v)), a), {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce`, `Object.keys` and `Object.assign` methods as follows:

```js
const 
      input = [ {name: 'Alex', date: '05/17/2023 10:32 PM', id: '00153168', priority: '3-Medium'}, {name: 'Peter', date: '05/17/2023 11:32 PM', id: '00153169', priority: '3-Medium'} ],
      
      output = input.reduce(
          (a,c,i) => i === 0 ? c : Object.assign(
              a,Object.keys(c).reduce(
                  (o,k) => Object.assign(
                      o,{[k]: Array.isArray(a[k]) ? [...a[k],c[k]] : [a[k],c[k]]}
                  ), {}
              )
          ), {}
      );
      
console.log( output );
```